# How to properly use one "current" array to manage multiple arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here's what I mean, I have an iOS app that I'm making a website version of. In Swift the method I made to handle the multiple arrays works fine. However, in JavaScript, it does not. The reason I made this system is to save many lines of code, and hopefully some performance too, since I perform a lot of statistics through various functions and I don't want to have to write switch statements for each array in each function.

Here's a simplified version of what I have with only two cases:
First, there's a variable which I'll simplify to `selectedCategory`, and is what the *switch* statements are based on.

```
function assignArray() {
  switch (selectedCategory) {
    case "one":
      currentArray.push(...categoryOneArray);
    case "two":
      currentArray.push(...categoryTwoArray);
  }
}

function updateArray() {
  switch (selectedCategory) {
    case "one":
      categoryOneArray.push(...currentArray);
      currentArray = [];
    case "two":
      categoryTwoArray.push(...currentArray);
      currentArray = [];
}
```

Here's how it works: When the user changes categories, first the `updateArray` function is called and adds everything to it from the `currentArray`. Then, the `selectedCategory` variable is changed and the `assignArray` function is called, adding everything from the respective category array to the `currentArray`.

The problem is that when switching from category one to two, or from two to one, the `currentArray` always shows up empty, but when logging both category arrays to console, the values are properly stored in them, just not the `currentArray`. Even after assigning everything from that array to the `currentArray`.

I've tried using several different methods, such as slice(), concat(), even a for loop.

Comment: I'm a little confused at what  you're trying to do...it sounds like your `updateArray` function is "backing up" the `currentArray` then clearing the `currentArray`. Then you effectively copying the `catagoryNArray` into the `currentArray`. There's a lot of copying arrays going on there, so I'm not sure why that would give you improved performance. Unfortunatley, without seeing directly how you're using the two functions together and logging to inspect, it's hard to provide concrete advice.

Comment: First, you may need to use `break` statements inside the `switch`, give a read to [MDN Switch Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch). Second, it will be better if you provide a fully example (with sample data) showing the issue, and what you expect to get as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be sure you're passing `selectedCategory` into `assignArray()` and `updateArray()`, otherwise neither of the switch blocks will have access to it.

Additionally, you should ensure that at the end of each switch case, you call [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break)

In the following code, the functionality of `changeCategory()` works as you described:

```
let categoryOneArray = ['one', '1', 'I']
let categoryTwoArray = ['two', '2', 'II']

let currentArray = []

function assignArray(selectedCategory) {
  switch (selectedCategory) {
    case 'one':
      currentArray.push(...categoryOneArray)
      break;
    case 'two':
      currentArray.push(...categoryTwoArray)
      break;
  }
}

function updateArray(selectedCategory) {
  switch (selectedCategory) {
    case 'one':
      categoryOneArray.push(...currentArray)
      currentArray = []
      break;
    case 'two':
      categoryTwoArray.push(...currentArray)
      currentArray = []
      break;
  }
}

function changeCategory(category) {
  currentArray = []
  updateArray(category)
  assignArray(category)
}

console.log(currentArray) // => []

changeCategory('one')
console.log(currentArray) // =>  ['one', '1', 'I']

changeCategory('two')
console.log(currentArray) // =>  ['two', '2', 'II']
```

Comment: I was missing the break statements for each case. It works flawlessly now. Thanks a lot!